# this font is really amazing, but dont know, help pls

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

[image]
can someone help me to find this font, this font is really good, but i cant find this font because the file is pdf. thanks.

Comment: If you are using Adobe Acrobat, in the menu File > Properties and then in the tab Fonts, it lists the fonts the document is using... unless it's scanned... :9

Comment: Well, FYI I found your PDF document on the internet, downloaded it and INDEED you can check the font names in the document properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typeface is [Neutraface Condensed](https://houseind.com/hi/neutraface-condensed) from the foundry [House Industries](https://houseind.com/). It seems to use some of the Alt glyphs (e.g., the W).

Comment: thanks sir, but Neue Condensed Alt type, thank you so much sir.